# Dynamodb Mapper Save functions not creating the item in table

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I tried using the dynamodbmapper for crud operations over the table. When I am using the save functionality from the mapper code getting executed with out any error or exceptions but when I scan the table records were not reflecting what could be the possible error I am doing in below way

```
try{
   User user = new User();
   /* added some dummy data to user object*/
   static AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
   static DynamoDBMapper dynamoDB = new DynamoDBMapper(client, new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.CLOBBER));
   dynamoDB.save(user);
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

My class object

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "users")
public class User {

private String id;
private String user_id;
private String email;
private String name;
private String mobile_no;
private Integer createdDate;
private Integer modifiedDate;


@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
public String getId(){
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "user_id")
public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}
public void setUser_id_ref(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "mobile_no")
public String getMobile_no() {
    return mobile_no;
}
public void setMobile_no(String mobile_no) {
    this.mobile_no = mobile_no;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "created_date")
public Integer getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
public void setCreatedDate(Integer createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "modified_date")
public Integer getModifiedDate() {
    return modifiedDate;
}
public void setModifiedDate(Integer modifiedDate) {
    this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
}
```

For scanning i have used the command

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name users
```

Result for the above command is coming as below

```
{
"Items": [],
"Count": 0,
"ScannedCount": 0,
"ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

Table Description

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name users
{
"Table": {
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "id",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }
    ],
    "TableName": "users",
    "KeySchema": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "id",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
        }
    ],
    "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "CreationDateTime": "2022-09-29T19:33:02.692000+05:30",
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "LastDecreaseDateTime": "2022-09-29T19:45:29.763000+05:30",
        "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
    }
 }
```

How ever I tried creating a test class where I just have hashkey attribute and tried saving the data it got persisted

```
package com.moneyview.model.dynamo;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
```

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScalarAttributeType;

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "users")
public class UserTest {

private String id;

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
public String getId(){
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

test code for inserting

```
public void testinsertItem(){
    try{
        UserTest test = new UserTest();
        test.setId("8a8180967e8b5112017e8b99268702df");
        dynamoDB.save(test);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong while inserting the records to DynamoDb");
    }
}
```

When I tried scanning the table

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name users
```

Result:

```
{
"Items": [
    {
        "id": {
            "S": "8a8180967e8b5112017e8b99268702df"
        }
    }
],
"Count": 1,
"ScannedCount": 1,
"ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

not sure where I am doing wrong or if there is any issue in the config please help me

Answer (score 0):

The code which you shared is correct, and the item should be persisted.

However, you would need to show your full class, and confirm how you are checking the item exists?

You mention it doesn't exist when your `Scan`? Are you scanning from your code directly after writing? Check that you have made your `Scan` Strongly Consistent to ensure you get the latest value.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-ConsistentRead

If this does not resolve the issue, I will be able to help you further when you share the rest of your code.

---

Reviewing your updated code it seems pretty fine, I did notice some issues with the setters you defined, but i'm not certain that is your issue. The below code snippet works for me:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.*;

import java.util.List;

public class UserOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDB = new DynamoDBMapper(client, new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.CLOBBER));

        User myUser = new User();
        myUser.setId("1");

        try{
            dynamoDB.save(myUser);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                .withConsistentRead(Boolean.TRUE);

        try{
            List<User> scanResult = dynamoDB.scan(User.class, scanExpression);
            for (User user : scanResult) {
                System.out.println(user.getId());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "users")
    public static class User {

        private String id;
        private String user_id;
        private String email;
        private String name;
        private String mobile_no;
        private Integer createdDate;
        private Integer modifiedDate;


        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "user_id")
        public String getUserId() {
            return user_id;
        }

        public void setUserId(String user_id) {
            this.user_id = user_id;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "email")
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "name")
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "mobile_no")
        public String getMobileNo() {
            return mobile_no;
        }

        public void setMobileNo(String mobile_no) {
            this.mobile_no = mobile_no;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "created_date")
        public Integer getCreatedDate() {
            return createdDate;
        }

        public void setCreatedDate(Integer createdDate) {
            this.createdDate = createdDate;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "modified_date")
        public Integer getModifiedDate() {
            return modifiedDate;
        }

        public void setModifiedDate(Integer modifiedDate) {
            this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if your did not have log statements inside your `catch` block but that is one thing you should definitely add. Should that fail, I would take a look at the following:

1. IAM policy, do you have the correct permissions
2. Internet access, does where you are executing the code from have a path to the DynamoDB endpoint?

Comment: Hi i have updated my question, dynamodb scan was done from my terminal where i am getting 0 results even after successfull execution of code

Comment: i have updated the question as per your comments

Comment: added table description details as well

Comment: even with consistent read records were not present

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know how that goes. Try the Scan from the code you do the write.

Comment: hey when i have created a test class where i just have hashkey id and tried using the save the class and it was getting saved successfully, I will update that code as well

Comment: I have added few more points can you please look into that and let me know if it helps

Comment: Pleas fix the naming convention of your getters/setters (copy mine). It is likely the issue. You should see this in an error message from the catch block, are you printing the error message?

Comment: it is not going into catch block at all  that is the reason im not able to figure understand where its going wrong code getting executed without any failure but data is not getting persisted

Comment: Did you change your getter and setters?